# Prove a subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is exactly a plane if there are vectors $u,v,w\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent and

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, euclidean-geometry, cross-product

Prove that a subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is exactly a plane, if there exists vectors $u,v,w \in \mathbb{R}^3$, such that $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent and

$$E = u + \mathbb{R}v + \mathbb{R}w$$

**Hint:** Let $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be two linearly independent vectors. It can be used that a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is perpendicular to the Cross Product

$$ v \times w := 
\begin{pmatrix}
v_2w_3 - v_3w_2, \\
v_3w_1 - v_1w_3, \\
v_1w_2 - v_2w_1
\end{pmatrix}^T$$

exactly if $x = \lambda v + \mu w$ for some $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$

---

There are several equation that can describe a plane

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_planes_in_three-dimensional_space#Point%E2%80%93normal_form_and_general_form_of_the_equation_of_a_plane

For example
$$n_1(x - x_0) + n_2(y - y_0) + n_3(z - z_0) = 0$$ where $n = (n_1, n_2, n_3)$ is a vector normal (perpendicular) to the plane, and $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is a point on the plane.

Then there is also the definition above
$$r = r_0 + s \cdot v + t \cdot w$$
where $r_0$ is a point on the plane, and $v$ and $w$ are two linearly independent vectors that span the plane.

In our case, the cross product in the hint obviously gives us a perpendicular vector, so we can find $n = (n_1, n_2, n_3)$. The vector $x$ in the hint is assumed to be perpendicular to the Cross Product, which means it lies in the plane. But how does that help ? What should I do next ?

Comment: Hint: $E-u$ is the plane passing through the origin spanned by $v$ and $w$ (or equivalently, normal to $v\times w$).

Comment: @blargoner yes in fact, $u$ is just a translation vector that shifts everything. How does that help ? The dot product of the normal vector with $v$ or $w$ will always be zero

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confused about. Is it the possibility that $u\ne 0$ that's causing you trouble?

Comment: @blargoner I don't really know what to prove actually. We can build a cross product to find a normal vector, we can use $E - u$ to find the plane through the origin, we can use that there is a vector perpendicular to the cross product $x = \lambda v + \mu w$, but how does that prove what they ask ?

Comment: You need to prove that $E$ is an (affine) plane, i.e. $E$ is described by the equation of a plane. Let $u=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $n=(n_1,n_2,n_3)=u\times v\ne0$. Do you see why $E$ is the set of points $(x,y,z)$ satisfying the first equation for a plane you wrote down?

Comment: @blargoner yes I see, $n$ is normal to the plane. At the same time $u$ makes the plane shift from the origin and $v$ and $w$ span the plane. The normal vector $n$ can be obtained by the cross product of $v$ and $w$. But do I need to write down this ? Can that be considered a proof ? Or am I missing something ? I just don’t see what to prove actually, I can write down everything I said above but is that a proof ? I appreciate your help by the way

Comment: In my opinion the question and the "hint" are foolish. An affine subspace of an affine space $\mathcal E$ is usually defined (up to minor variants) as a set of the form
$$\mathcal F=P+F,$$
where $P$ is some point of $\mathcal E$ and $F$ is a linear subspace of the linear space $E$ attached to $\mathcal E.$
It is an affine plane iff $F$ is a linear plane, i.e. spanned by two linearly independent vectors. There is nothing to prove. It is "the" definition.

Comment: @AnneBauval I agree with you, but I assume the question is being asked in a context where vector plane (through the origin) has been defined in terms a normal vector or corresponding equation.

Comment: @blargoner yes if I remember well, they defined it like that in the course. I mean they defined it like $r = r_0 + s \cdot v + t \cdot w$ where $r_0$ is a point, and $v,w$ are two linearly independent vectors. $r_0$ can be the point $(0,0,0)$ or something else. They also said that a plane can be defined as $n_1(x - x_0) + n_2(y - y_0) + n_3(z - z_0) = 0$ where $n$ is a normal vector to the plane, but from what I remember they talked mainly about $r = r_0 + s \cdot v + t \cdot w$